# Are there any techniques to indicate if a html select element is "used"?

Tags: html, html-select

Imagine I have some webapp with a lot of different filters, which impact e.g. search results on a page.

The filters are optional and I use select element. The first option always means, that the filter is not used and says something like "not used" or "select xyz".

I'm looking now for a way to make it possible to see in a quick glance which filters are currently used and which are not, e.g. by changing the color or background-color.

I didn't find a way to do this via CSS yet, maybe its not possible without javascript?
Solutions needs only to work in latest Chrome.

Comment: When do you want the colors to change? As soon as the user changes the dropdown? When the page reloads?

Comment: Not without a server-side, or JavaScript, component, no. There is [`:checked`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked), but that's only for (predictably) checkboxes and radio elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the color of the dropdown to change immediately as soon as the user changes the selection (without reloading the page), you'll have to use JavaScript. Something like:

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
    function changeColor(element)
    {
        if (element.selectedIndex != 0)
            element.style.backgroundColor = "green";
        else
            element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
</script>

<select onchange="changeColor(this)">
```

So that's how you would change the color as soon as the user changes the selection.

To change it on page reload, you would have to use some server-side scripting language (which I'm assuming you're using already). So when creating the `<select>` element, you would check to see if its value has been set. If you were using PHP, it might look something like this:

```
<select name="mySelect" style="background-color:<?php echo ($_POST["mySelect"] == "select xyz" ? "red" : "green"); ?>;">
```

Comment: okay, I was afraid that it's not possible via css only. I know how do it in javascript/php but thanks for your answer anyway